# Is a 2002 Nissan Pathfinder Rear window center mount stop light compatible with a 2011 Nissan Pathfinder silver edition stop light?

Tags: nissan, pathfinder, part-interchange, third-brake-light

Rear window stop light center mount 6.0 4 wheel drive

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

No. The 2002 Pathfinder is a 2nd generation, while the 2011 is a 3rd generation. The 3rd brake lights won't swap over.